# Splitting a String with Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a String in the following format :

Sat, 09 Jul 2011 05:38:24 GMT

I would have an output like this :

09 Jul 2011
05:38:24

Thanks.

[EDIT]
I have tried many solutions, I have had errors. I will re-explain the problem. I have an XML file where I have a node :  Tue, 05 Jul 2011 10:10:30 GMT from which I would like to extract two separated String as illustrated above. 
I have tried this code:

```
register /usr/lib/pig/piggybank.jar; 
items = LOAD ' depeche/2011_7_10_12_30_rss.txt' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('item') AS  (item:chararray); 
source_name = FOREACH items GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(item, '<link>(.*)</link>', 1) AS  link:chararray, 
REGEX_EXTRACT(item, '<title>(.*)</title>', 1) AS  title:chararray, 
REGEX_EXTRACT(item, '<description>(.*)</description>',  1) AS description:chararray, 
REGEX_EXTRACT(item, '<pubDate>(.*)</pubDate>', 1) AS  pubdate:chararray, 
sortie = FOREACH pubdate GENERATE SUBSTRING((chararray)$0, 4, 25);
illustrate sortie;
```

error:

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 21, column 333>         mismatched input '=' expecting SEMI_COLON
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### EDITED ANSWER:

That example is a bit more clear ... I grabbed an RSS feed example, and did a quick test.  The code below worked using a sample which contained all of the elements in your example above.  I used REGEX_EXTRACT instead of SUBSTRING to get the pubdate, however.

--rss.pig

```
REGISTER piggybank.jar

items = LOAD 'rss.txt' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('item') AS  (item:chararray);

data = FOREACH items GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(item, '<link>(.*)</link>', 1) AS  link:chararray, 
REGEX_EXTRACT(item, '<title>(.*)</title>', 1) AS  title:chararray,
REGEX_EXTRACT(item, '<description>(.*)</description>',  1) AS description:chararray,
REGEX_EXTRACT(item, '<pubDate>.*(\\d{2}\\s[a-zA-Z]{3}\\s\\d{4}\\s\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}).*</pubDate>', 1) AS  pubdate:chararray;

dump data;
```

--rss.txt

```
<rss version="2.0">
   <channel>
      <title>News</title>
      <link>http://www.hannonhill.com</link>
      <description>Hannon Hill News</description>
      <language>en-us</language>
      <pubDate>Tue, 10 Jun 2003 04:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
      <generator>Cascade Server</generator>
      <webMaster>webmaster@hannonhill.com</webMaster>
      <item>
         <title>News Item 1</title>
         <link>http://www.hannonhill.com/news/item1.html</link>
         <description>Description of news item 1 here.</description>
         <pubDate>Tue, 03 Jun 2003 09:39:21 GMT</pubDate>
         <guid>http://www.hannonhill.com/news/item1.html</guid>
      </item>
      <item>
         <title>News Item 2</title>
         <link>http://www.hannonhill.com/news/item2.html</link>
         <description>Description of news item 2 here.</description>
         <pubDate>Fri, 30 May 2003 11:06:42 GMT</pubDate>
         <guid>http://www.hannonhill.com/news/item2.html</guid>
      </item>
      <item>
         <title>News Item 3</title>
         <link>http://www.hannonhill.com/news/item3.html</link>
         <description>Description of news item 3 here.</description>
         <pubDate>Tue, 20 May 2003 08:56:02 GMT</pubDate>
         <guid>http://www.hannonhill.com/news/item3.html</guid>
      </item>
   </channel>
</rss>
```

**Results for rss.pig:**

```
(http://www.hannonhill.com/news/item1.html,News Item 1,Description of news item 1 here.,03 Jun 2003 09:39:21)
(http://www.hannonhill.com/news/item2.html,News Item 2,Description of news item 2 here.,30 May 2003 11:06:42)
(http://www.hannonhill.com/news/item3.html,News Item 3,Description of news item 3 here.,20 May 2003 08:56:02)
```

### ORIGINAL ANSWER:

There are several methods that would work here, so I'll cover two:  **SUBSTRING** and **REGEX_EXTRACT**.

If your string length is constant, then you can use the builtin [SUBSTRING](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#substring) function.  Think of it like the `cut` command in Linux.

`OUTPUT = FOREACH INPUT GENERATE SUBSTRING((chararray)$0, 4, 25);`

Otherwise, you can use the builtin [REGEX_EXTRACT](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/func.html#regex-extract) to pull the string that you're looking for.  Given the example, the easiest regex match that I came up with was to begin the string with the first digit, and end with the last digit, capturing all characters in between.

`OUTPUT = FOREACH INPUT GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT((chararray)$0, '([\d].*[\d])', 1);`

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried both commands, but I have had this error : [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 21, column 333> mismatched input '=' expecting SEMI_COLON.

I will edit my question to explain the problem.